# Does the ellipsoid intercept sea level markers?

Tags: geodesy

I know the geoid represents the gravity surface as if mean sea level, but came across a comment that the geoid was created by taking the ellipsoid, setting the volume constant and changing that surface to derive the equipotential surface.

So the ellipsoid was needed to make that geoid. Does anyone know if the original ellipsoid derived with satellite data is constrained to US Navy (I guess) sea level markers? That would provide set points to bend and shape around to form a geoid.